# How to verify if a file has a correct extension when a button "SEND" is pressed in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

I'm working on a GUI using MFC. I need that the end-user selects a `.hex` file. I'm using `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` for browse files. Somebody can help me with `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` usage. I'M NEW USING MFC. If you need more details just tell me.

Thanks in advance for your help (sorry, English is not my native language).

Comment: As a starting point, check out the CMFCEditBrowseCtrl example code in the [MFC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=vs-2019). If you have tried that already but are stuck, please update the question with your code and details about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`EnableFileBrowseButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=vs-2019#enablefilebrowsebutton).

```
//Open the specified file format
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl m_EditBrowse;
m_EditBrowse.EnableFileBrowseButton(_T(""),_T("hex Files(*.hex)|*.hex|"));
```